# Zend Studio Intellisense + zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, zend-studio

I've got a very annoying problem with my Zend studio.
I have a zend framework project I am working on. The actual zend framework code is inside my project (in library folder) and then ZS seems to reference to its own version of zend framework. As the result, I get 2 versions of the same function/class in my intellisense which is annoying to say the least.

Today I had the last drop of patience with zend studio when I showed 4 copies of the same class (imagine what's its like looking at a large namespace times 4!).

So, how do I remove all references inside ZS to its own version of ZF?
Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look at the "location" field in each case and find out where they all are.

I believe that Project->Properties->PHP Include Path will allow you to remove references to the other ZFs.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP Explorer, r-click on the project name. Select Include Path > Configure Include Path. There are four buttons at the top of that property page - Source, Projects, Libraries, Order. Check the Source and Libraries property sheets to ensure that the ZF library in your project is the only one present.

Hope that helps.